# Google maps geolocation not working in ubuntu14.04

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ubuntu, google-maps-api-3, google-geolocation

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04**. I am facing an issue with google maps geo-location. I wrote a piece of code which shows geo-location map in my project, initially it worked fine. But I am facing an issue with this now. Even the link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation is always throwing an error. In **windows** it works fine but not in **Ubuntu**. I tried in various computers running on **Ubuntu**, I got same error.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my script code:

```
if(navigator.geolocation)
{
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, displayError, options);
}
var options = {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 30000,
                maximumAge: 0
              };
// SUCCESS(POSITION) FUCNTION FOR SHOWING CURRENT LOCATION OF THE USER
function success(position) {
  if(navigator.geolocation){
      var myLatLng={lat:position.coords.latitude , lng:position.coords.longitude}
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'),
      {
       center:myLatLng ,
       zoom: 8
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      });
  }
}
// IN THIS FUNCTION WE HAVE SET STANDARD LAT LNG FOR STANDARD MAP(IF GPS NOT AVAIALABLE)
function displayError(err) {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
          center: {lat: 28.644800, lng: 77.216721},
          zoom: 8
        });
};
```

Here is my html code:

```
<script src="
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VsGy.png)

Comment: you haven't mentioned which browser you are using .... ubuntu and windows are operating systems, chrome, firefox and edge are browsers

Comment: `is always throwing an error` - do we need to guess the error, or will you share it with us?

Comment: I tried in both browsers. And yes, we need to guess the error

Comment: Both? Any reason you can't name them

Comment: I tried in chrome and as well as in firefox browsers sir.

Comment: the real question is, what error is thrown

Comment: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, onError) is always returning onError.

Comment: OH MY GOD ... what's the damn error

Answer (score 0):

So, if you try get the current position in chrome, you need use security origins or `https` environment.

For more details: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only.

I hope help you!

Comment: I used security origins only. Even the link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation is passed in to the failure callback of the Geolocation APIs.

Comment: sorry, my last comment it was wrong, consider bellow:

See there two links: [http://d.pr/i/qqwf/4Cy2tLC8](http://d.pr/i/qqwf/4Cy2tLC8) is one screenshot of my test, [http://d.pr/i/1gERw/3XI54lVx](http://d.pr/i/1gERw/3XI54lVx) if you use the chrome as a browser, search for target icon (and click to open the box) in the address bar.